# Django rest nested serializer validation by id

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have following django-rest serializers:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FileModel
        fields = ('id', '_file')

class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = FileSerializer(many=True, required= False)
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('id', 'files')
```

And models

```
 class File(models.Model):
      some_obj = models.ForeignKey('SomeObj',related_name='files', blank=True, null=True)
      _file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

The problem comes, when I create SomeSerializer with existing File objects

```
s = SomeSerializer(data = {'files': [{'id' : 1}]})
s.is_valid()
s.errors
```

Returns

```
False
{'_file': [u'No file was submitted.']}
```

How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: can you show your models.py?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the message is pretty obvious. You don't provide "_file" to the serializer. This should fix:

```
s = SomeSerializer(data = {'files': [{'id' : 1, '_file': <somedata>}]})
```

Comment: I don't need to provide any data to **existing** file object with id=1.

Comment: Then you'll need to align your field constraints against what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`_file` field is missing, then if it's not required, set `required` to `False`:

```python
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    _file = serializer.FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FileModel
        fields = ('id', '_file')
```